# Adding a new item to a checklist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to create a checklist that allows users to add their own items.

This is part of my HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="checkbox65" id="checkbox65" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="checkbox65">Get directions for where you are going</label>
    </td>
</tr>
 <h3>
   My items
  </h3>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <label for="textinput4">Add new item</label>
    </td>
    <input name="new_item" id="textinput4" placeholder="" value="" type="text"
    />
</fieldset>
 <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" />
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
    $('#add').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $newRow = $this.closest('table').find('tr:first').clone();
        $newRow.find(':input').val('');
        $newRow.insertAfter($this.parent());
    });
</script>
```

But I just do not get any response..

Comment: my bad, didn't paste it in. 

Just below it. I'll edit question now.

Comment: your markup is invalid: you have elements not allowed as immediate children of a table element. you should first correct this issue

Comment: And where is parent element for `#add`?
And those overlapping `</td>` and `<fieldset>`... parser probably work in a wrong way with this markup.

Comment: I removed the extra </td> because it wasn't necessary. 

When it comes to the parent element for #add, I don't know what that is. I tried to relate the best answer from another post to my own code as best I could and didn't see anything in their html that indicated a parent for the #add.

Sounds like this is where I'm going wrong. Is the parent add the other item in the list surrounded by tr and td tags?

Answer (score 0):

### Is this what you need ?

### HTML

```
<h3>My items</h3>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="checkbox65">
                <input name="checkbox65" class="checkbox65" type="checkbox" />
                Get directions for where you are going
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr><td>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <label for="textinput4">
            Add new item
            <input name="new_item" id="textinput4" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <button id="add">Add</button>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Notice I've changed `id="checkbox65"` to `class="checkbox65"` because you can't use same id twice. Also changed `input type=submit` to `<button>` for `adding` new elements.

### JS

```
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $firstRow=$this.closest('table').find('tr:first');
    var $newRow = $firstRow.clone();
    $newRow.find(':input').prop('checked', false);
    $newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/avakut/3/edit).

**Update:** Or maybe [**this one**](http://jsbin.com/avakut/13/edit) or [**this one**](http://jsbin.com/avakut/15/edit).

Comment: This is great!

I made a simple adjustment or moving the last tr and td's because when pressing add it cloned everything, rather than just the checkbox text.

however, now I am faced with the problem that when pressing add, it does not take the value in input field and add that but rather the original input of "get directions for where.."

That's a fantastic website you're using! jsbin!

Comment: @user1875549, Check [example-1](http://jsbin.com/avakut/3/edit), [example-2](http://jsbin.com/avakut/13/edit), [example-3](http://jsbin.com/avakut/15/edit). Hope it helps.

Comment: DEMO is almost exactly what I want, if only it were posted what you wrote in the text box rather than the original text.

Comment: and yeah you've helped a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @user1875549, I've empty the new text box before I insert it in to the dom, do you want to keep the text box's value in to the new one ?

Comment: yeah and post it underneath the first check box

Comment: It was more like [this one](http://jsbin.com/avakut/3/edit).

But to have whatever you type into the text field posted, instead of repeating "get directions.."

Comment: @user1875549, Confused! Okay, simple question: Do you want to insert the exact copy of your first text box beneath the check box with the value containing in the text box  ?